# Special linear group action on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Where did I do mistakes in the following:

So the real special linear group $SL(3,\ \mathbb R)$ acts transitively on  the sphere $S^2$ and the isotropy of the point $(1,0,0)\in S^2$ is $H=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mathbb R & \mathbb R\\ 0 & * & * \\ 0 & * & * \end{pmatrix}$. Hence, $H$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2\times SL(2,\ \mathbb R)$ and so $\pi_1(H)=\mathbb Z$.

Now the exact sequence of the principal bundle $SL(3,\ \mathbb R)\to SL(3,\ \mathbb R)/H=S^2$ is
$$0\to \mathbb Z\to \pi_1(H)\to \mathbb Z_2\to 0$$
which gives us that $\pi_1(H)=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SL(3,\Bbb R)$ does *not* act on the sphere $S^2$. The groups $O(3)$ and $SO(3)$ do, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but why $SL(3,\mathbb R)$ does not act on $S^2$? how to prove that?

Comment: Does it map vectors of length $1$ to vectors of length $1$?

Comment: Ok I see, but I am confused now because $SL(n+1,\mathbb R)$ acts on $S^n$ for odd $n$ (as in p 396 in Projective and Cayley-Klein Geometry https://books.google.ca/books?id=xvlt-YM07WwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Projective+and+Cayley-Klein+Geometry+page+400&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVrInurITmAhWyJzQIHS3hBDIQ6wEILDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I can't see your reference. The action is obviously not linear. What is the action?

Comment: Actually, it was a different part of the song I was thinking of:  Where's the action? Where's the game?
Gotta have the game
Of we'll die from shame
It's the oldest established, permanent floating
Crap game in New York!

Comment: @TedShifrin Projective and Cayley-Klein Geometries By Arkadij L. Onishchik, Rolf Sulanke.   Example 4 page 396